# Time complexity of algorithms with recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

A is a n-by-n matrix. Consider a function algo(A) which returns:

```
def algo(A):
    return algo(A[:n//2, :n//2]) + algo(A[:n//2, n//2:]) + algo(A[n//2:, :n//2]) + \
           algo(A[n//2:, n//2:]) + A.transpose() * A
```

The formula of time complexity is as `O(log(a*n) + n^b)`. The question asks to solve `a` and `b`. I gather that due to the matrix multiplication, b=3. But, what is a? Could you give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really matter what `a` is; whatever it is, the result collapses to `O(n^b)`.

Comment: @chepner You're absolutely right. But, the question asks to solve a... I'd better modify the post a bit to avoid confusion.

Comment: What is the base case of this recursion? If A is 0x0 ?

Comment: @Daniel I guess we can say the base case is when A is 1*1, and algo(A) simply returns A^2.

Comment: log *an* = log *a* + log *n*, so O(log *an*) = O(log *n*) regardless of what *a* is; that is, all positive values of *a* are equally correct (or equally incorrect). Are you sure you've understood the question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of `A` will be `N = n^2`, then the time complexity of the `algo` is `T(N) = 4T(N/4) + N^1.5` if the multiplication is done in a simple case (I mean we can use something much smarter likes Strassen algorithm). Now, from master theorem we knew that `T(N) = \Theta(N^1.5) = \Theta(n^3)`.

Therefore, `a` can be any constant value.

Comment: Yes. I think master theorem is the key!

Answer (score 0):

First we take in consideration that matrix multiplication takes O(n^3).

Always we call `algo`, we call it again with a quarter of A.

```
    T(algo(A))
        |___________
        | | | |     |       
1.     algo(A/4)  O(n³) = 4T(algo(A/4)) + O(n^3)
2.        .
...       .
log(n).   .
```

In line 1, we have 4 call, in line 2, 16 calls, in line **i**, we have 4^(i) calls.

The total number of **algo** calls is **C** = 4^1 + ... + 4^*log*(n), since every line we multiply the calls of the previous line by 4, so we can bound it to:

```
C = 4^log(n)
C = log(x)      so 2^x = 4^log(n) = 2^(2*log(n))
C = log( 2*log(n) )
```

The total complexity is O(Cn³), since each call performs an O(n³) operation.

If the total complexity is in the shape O(*log*(a*n) + n^b), then we can simplify:

O( *log* (2 *log* (n)) * n³) = O( [1 + *log*(*log*(n))] n³ ) = O( n³ + *log*(*log*(n))n³ ).

As the n³ is outside the *log* function, we can force it to go in:

O( n³ + *log*(*log*(n))n³ ) = O( n³ + *log*( *log*(n) * 2^(n^3) ) ).

If *log*( *log*(n) * 2^(n^3) ) = **a** * n,

**a = [ *log*( *log*(n) * 2^(n^3) ) ] / n**,

**b = 3**.